# find production time based on start time and end time php

Tags: php

I have to find the production time of an employee, how many hours and minutes he takes to complete the project.

My condition is,

`1. I have start and end datetime of an employee`

`2. I have 3 break time.`

`3. The break times should be subtracted if break times is in between start and end time.`

`4. The working time is between 08:30 to 18:30, the time beyond this working time should be subtracted.`

All the above conditions should be achieved. I have tried to achieve this but for one day work the code is working fine. But for more than one day the break this is subtracted only once and working time not subtracted.

```
$start = "01-01-2018 09:00";
$end = "02-01-2018 18:30";

$break1_start = "11:00";
$break1_end = "11:15";

$break2_start = "13:00";
$break2_end = "13:30";

$break3_start = "16:00";
$break3_end = "16:15";

//work time
$break4_start = "18:30";
$break4_end = "08:30";

$break1 = 0;
$break2 = 0;
$break3 = 0;
$break4 = 0;

//Break 1
if($break1_start >= date("H:i", strtotime($start)) and $break1_start <= date("H:i", strtotime($end))) {
    if($break1_end >= date("H:i", strtotime($start)) and $break1_end <= date("H:i", strtotime($end))) {
        $break1 = strtotime($break1_end) - strtotime($break1_start);
    }
    else {
        $end = date("H:i", strtotime($end));
        $break1 = strtotime($break1_end) - strtotime($end);
    }
}
else if($break1_end >= date("H:i", strtotime($start)) and $break1_end <= date("H:i", strtotime($end))) {
    $start = date("H:i", strtotime($start));
    $break1 = strtotime($break1_end) - strtotime($start);
}

//Break 2
if($break2_start >= date("H:i", strtotime($start)) and $break2_start <= date("H:i", strtotime($end))) {
    if($break2_end >= date("H:i", strtotime($start)) and $break2_end <= date("H:i", strtotime($end))) {
        $break2 = strtotime($break2_end) - strtotime($break2_start);
    }
    else {
        $end = date("H:i", strtotime($end));
        $break2 = strtotime($break2_end) - strtotime($end);
    }
}
else if($break2_end >= date("H:i", strtotime($start)) and $break2_end <= date("H:i", strtotime($end))) {
    $start = date("H:i", strtotime($start));
    $break2 = strtotime($break2_end) - strtotime($start);
}

//Break 3
if($break3_start >= date("H:i", strtotime($start)) and $break3_start <= date("H:i", strtotime($end))) {
    if($break3_end >= date("H:i", strtotime($start)) and $break3_end <= date("H:i", strtotime($end))) {
        $break3 = strtotime($break3_end) - strtotime($break3_start);
    }
    else {
        $end = date("H:i", strtotime($end));
        $break3 = strtotime($break3_end) - strtotime($end);
    }
}
else if($break3_end >= date("H:i", strtotime($start)) and $break3_end <= date("H:i", strtotime($end))) {
    $start = date("H:i", strtotime($start));
    $break3 = strtotime($break3_end) - strtotime($start);
}

//Work time
if($break4_start >= date("H:i", strtotime($start)) and $break4_start <= date("H:i", strtotime($end))) {
    if($break4_end >= date("H:i", strtotime($start)) and $break4_end <= date("H:i", strtotime($end))) {
        $break4 = strtotime($break4_end) - strtotime($break4_start);
    }
    else {
        $end = date("H:i", strtotime($end));
        $break4 = strtotime($break4_end) - strtotime($end);
    }
}
else if($break4_end >= date("H:i", strtotime($start)) and $break4_end <= date("H:i", strtotime($end))) {
    $start = date("H:i", strtotime($start));
    $break4 = strtotime($break4_end) - strtotime($start);
}

$diff = strtotime($end) - strtotime($start);
$diff = $diff - $break1 - $break2 - $break3 - $break4;

$hours = floor($diff / 3600);
$minutes = floor(($diff / 60) % 60);
$seconds = $diff % 60;

echo "$hours:$minutes:$seconds";
```

From the above code,

`1. All the break time should be subtracted twice because break time comes twice in the given start and end time.`

The `output` for the above given start and end time and all break time should be `17:30:00`

But now the output for the above code is `1458:30:0`.

How to achieve my conditions and output? I am really stuck here. Could any one help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you calculate total production time and then subtract total break time.

Comment: @Ronak Bokaria: I want to check the break time is between start and end time.

Comment: Sorry but rationally if the break time is in between the start and end then 0nly consider the time and add that to total break time and at last subtract that from production. If break's time is less then end time then only consider it.

Comment: I will try that. Can you show me an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your condition 4, "The working time is between 08:30 to 18:30, the time beyond this working time should be subtracted." but your start day is `$start = "01-01-2018 09:00";` I believe it should be `$start = "01-01-2018 08:30";` and your day break i.e. `break4_..` should be :

```
$break4_start = "18:30";
$break4_end = "08:30";
```

I calculated total working time and break time in minutes, later will change in hours and minutes.

As per these assumptions, I tried to get calculate total working hours and minutes.

```
$start = "01-01-2018 08:30";
$end = "01-01-2018 18:30";

$starti = strtotime($start);
$endi = strtotime($end);

$startDate = date('Y-m-d', $starti);
$nextDayDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($startDate. '+1 day'));

$break1_start = "11:00";
$break1_end = "11:15";

$break2_start = "13:00";
$break2_end = "13:30";

$break3_start = "16:00";
$break3_end = "16:15";

$break4_start = "18:30";
$break4_end = "08:30";

$datetime1 = new DateTime($start);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($end);
//get the difference of two dates
$interval = $datetime2->diff($datetime1);
//01-01-2018 to 02-01-2018, total working days will be 2 but `$interval->days` returns 1 so added one into this.

//01-01-2018 to 01-01-2018, diff function returns 0 so in that case it will count 1.

$totalDays = $interval->days + 1;
$totalBreak = 0;
//run a loop for total days to calculate total break times
for($i=0; $i < $totalDays; $i++){
    $break1_starti = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($startDate .$break1_start . ' +'.$i.' day')));
    $break1_endi = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($startDate .$break1_end . ' +'.$i.' day')));
    if($break1_starti >= $starti && $break1_endi <= $endi){
        $totalBreak += ($break1_endi - $break1_starti)/60;
    }
    $break2_starti = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($startDate .$break2_start . ' +'.$i.' day')));
    $break2_endi = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($startDate .$break2_end . ' +'.$i.' day')));
    if($break2_starti >= $starti && $break2_endi <= $endi){
        $totalBreak += ($break2_endi - $break2_starti)/60;
    }
    $break3_starti = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($startDate .$break3_start . ' +'.$i.' day')));
    $break3_endi = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($startDate .$break3_end . ' +'.$i.' day')));
    if($break3_starti >= $starti && $break3_endi <= $endi){
        $totalBreak += ($break3_endi - $break3_starti)/60;
    }
}

//now calculate day break
if($interval->days){
    $break4_starti = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($startDate .$break4_start)));
    $break4_endi = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($nextDayDate .$break4_end )));
    if($break4_starti >= $starti && $break4_endi <= $endi){
        $daysBreak = ($break4_endi - $break4_starti)/60;
    }
    $totalBreak += ($daysBreak * $interval->days);
}
echo "<br />totalBreak = ".$totalBreak;
echo "<br />totalMinutes = ".$totalMinutes = $minutsDiff = $interval->d * 24 * 60 + $interval->h * 60 + $interval->i;
echo "<br />totalWorkingMinutes = ".$totalWorkingMinutes = $totalMinutes - $totalBreak;
echo "<br />hours = ".$hours = floor($totalWorkingMinutes/60);
echo "<br />minutes = ".$minutes = $totalWorkingMinutes - $hours*60;
echo "<br />Total Working time = ". $hours.':'.$minutes;
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/LRcrQ)